# Why does connecting to my server IP address using a Windows 7 machine give Connection Timeout exception?

Tags: java, windows-7, client-server, static-ip-address

I have a Java Server which is hosted from my iMac on a static IP Address. One of my friends uses the Java Client application on a Windows 7 laptop .
My server client application was working just fine until yesterday when the client application on my friend’s pc suddenly crashed and he had to restart the system. Following restart, whenever he would try to connect to my server , it would show connection timeout.
I rebooted my server and connected to it from an outside network and its working just fine.
Since my sever also hosts a webpage , I recommended my friend to try and open that using the Laptop’s Chrome but even the webpage shows “taking too long” and fails to load.

**I told my friend to open the same webpage(hosted by my server on the same IP) using his mobile phone(on the same broadband network) and IT DID OPEN!**

***The Problem***

1. My friend’s windows 7 laptop is somehow blocking connections to my server’s static IP Address ( even after I made him turn off all anti virus softwares )
2. The problem is with the laptop and not with his broadband network since his mobile device can connect to my server easily PLUS I myself have tested my server from other outside network.
3. The issue is not being resolved even on turning the system off and then on again or even rebooting the modem(friend’s)

**My Question**

What could be the reason why the Windows 7 os suddenly started blocking all connections to my server IP and how to resolve it ?